# Monitor peak memory usage with dotMemoryUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, memory, jetbrains-ide, memory-profiling

Is it possible to get peak memory usage with `dotMemoryUnit` from JetBrains?

I know that it is possible to see memory traffic: allocations and collections. But what if I want to see that during my test the peak memory usage never exceeded a certain amount?

E.g. if my application allocates 100mb, collects it and then allocates 100mb more, followed by a collection, that is fine. But if it allocates 200mb at once, I want to catch it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible for now, but we planning to implement such possibility in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will accept my own `PeakWorkingSet64` solution for now then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem I tried to solve is easily solvable without dotMemoryUnit.

Using [PeakWorkingSet64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64(v=vs.110).aspx) did the trick for me.

The test using `NUnit` might look like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_not_peak_more_than_200_mb()
    {
        var memoryCap = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
        var sut = new SystemUnderTest();
        sut.DoMemoryHeavyOperation()
        var peakWorkingSet = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PeakWorkingSet64;
        Assert.That(peakWorkingSet, Is.LessThan(memoryCap));
    }
```